# Status bar overlapping

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I trying to put constraint on my `webview` because its overlapping on the status bar.

I'm using Xcode 9.2.

When scrolling I don't want that the status bar go "translucent" or anything because its not readable I want a hard white but I cannot find the solution. I have put constraints but they don't seem to work.

Any ideas? I don't want to hide the status bar I want it not to be under my content.

[image: Overlapping screenshot]

[image: Storyboard]

[[image: Iphone Screenshot]

[[image: Iphone Screenshot]

```
//
//  FirstViewController.swift
//  Crossfit 514
//
//  Created by Admin on 2017-12-01.
//  Copyright © 2017 Crossfit 514. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import WebKit
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

@IBOutlet weak var constraint: WKWebView!
override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://crossfit514.fliipapp.com/")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}}
```

Comment: show us storyboard, what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to make status bar on top not under my webview

Answer (score 0):

I think you must give top constraint to your webView as 20 from your superView and it won't overlap. (as I have understood your question)

Comment: I have try(I added picture of my storyboard) but with -20 or 20 as Top Constraint nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding an empty UIView at the top of 20 height and the full width of the screen, and add constraints accordingly.